# Как расшифровывается сообщение зашифрованное чужим публичным ключом? XMPP

Tags: xmpp, gpg

Общаясь в XMPP с шифрованием OpenPGP, я увидел одну непонятность.

Если отправить сообщение с компьютера, а затем зайти в чат со смартфона я увижу это самое отправленное сообщение.

Как я могу видеть сообщение на телефоне, если его может расшифровать только приватный ключ собеседника которого у меня нет?

Может ли быть такое, что на сервере хранятся сразу две копии сообщения зашифрованные двумя публичными ключами?

Comment: Расшифровать данные зашифрованные AES без ключа ближайшие 100 лет будет невозможно

Comment: @foresle cтранно. А вы уверены, что сообщение и в самом деле зашифровано?

Comment: @andreymal Я отправил несколько сообщений, а затем зашел со смартфона и сделал снимок экрана, несколько секунд проходит перед тем, как сообщение расшифровывается. [Dino in Linux](https://i.imgur.com/lw1j6Lt.png), [Conversations in Android 1](https://i.imgur.com/9B93aqr.png), [Conversations in Android 2](https://i.imgur.com/v9Dpoqi.png). Шифрование повсюду OpenPGP, OMEMO принудительно отключил.

Comment: @DiD Вы про увеличение производительности ЭВМ? Или всмысле если сейчас начать расшифровку?

Comment: @artemgh Я про шифрование с 4096-битным ключем (или сколько там сейчас по умолчанию в PGP)... Попробуйте подобрать

Comment: Если сообщение расшифровывается, то скорее всего ключ один. Кроме того разве тот же Conversations поддерживает несколько ключей PGP на один контакт?

Comment: @DiD я понял Вас, просто Вы про то что если сейчас начать расшифровывать, или про то что новые технологии научатся расшифровывать?

Comment: @artemgh Перебирать они всегда умели, просто там приблизительно `10^1234` вариантов, перебирая даже по миллиону в секунду, это дело бесполезно. и я не уверен, что компьютеры через 100 лет будут на порядки мощнее, может в 1000 раз, может в 1000000 раз, но это сильно не сыграет роли

Comment: @DiD я про это Вам и говорю, просто  Вы так написали, я думал развивается какая-то новая технология, а я не знаю)